# Can't get CBR when converting MP4 to Mono MP3

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, bitrate

Having read at least a dozen other answers, it seems that the `b:a 96k` parameter should be producing a MP3 with a constant bitrate (CBR), yet I can only get Variable bitrates.

The latest variation of ffmpeg that comes closest is below.  I don't believe I'm missing anything, so are the other values interfering?

**UPDATE: replace input/output with the latest results.**

From MediaInfo:

```
General
Complete name                            : C:\3024.mp3
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
File size                                : 124 MiB
Duration                                 : 2 h 59 min
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 96.0 kb/s
Track name                               : My Title
Writing library                          : LAME3.100
major_brand                              : mp42
minor_version                            : 0
compatible_brands                        : mp42mp41

Audio
Format                                   : MPEG Audio
Format version                           : Version 1
Format profile                           : Layer 3
Duration                                 : 2 h 59 min
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 96.0 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 1 channel
Sampling rate                            : 44.1 kHz
Frame rate                               : 38.281 FPS (1152 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 124 MiB (100%)
Writing library                          : LAME3.100
```

`ffmpeg -i 3024.mp4 -metadata title="My Title" -vn -ar 44100 -ac 1 -b:a 96k 3024.mp3`

````
ffmpeg version 4.1.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20190212
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '20221011_regular_3024.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2022-10-12T06:53:10.000000Z
  Duration: 02:59:59.36, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1297 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1198 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 60k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-10-12T06:53:10.000000Z
      handler_name    : ?Mainconcept Video Media Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 93 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-10-12T06:53:11.000000Z
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (aac (native) -> mp3 (libmp3lame))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mp3, to '20221011_regular_3024.mp3':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    TIT2            : Regular Meeting on Tuesday, October 11th, 2022
    TSSE            : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 96 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-10-12T06:53:11.000000Z
      handler_name    : #Mainconcept MP4 Sound Media Handler
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libmp3lame
size=  126556kB time=02:59:59.36 bitrate=  96.0kbits/s speed= 126x
video:0kB audio:126555kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000393% ```
````

Comment: It could be MediaInfo is misreporting. Maybe try a different tool? (one post elsewhere says if bitrate is a nice number like "96.0" then it is CBR (I tend to agree with this quick-n-dirty check)

Comment: Alas. no.  Same result with other tools, MediaInfo was just the easiest to include in the question.

Comment: hmm, looking at the source code, the only way your command isn't encoding in CBR is if `-abr` option is default to 1 (it doesn't appear so). Maybe try adding `-abr 0` encoder option